# Как вынести блок if в отдельный кусок кода?

Tags: javascript, функции, if

В функциях повторяется условие.
Как вынести его в отдельную функцию, чтобы код не повторялся?

```js
const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  if (min < 0 || max < 0 || max < min) {
    return null; 
  }
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const getRandomFractionalNumber = (min, max, point) => {
  if (min < 0 || max < 0 || max < min) {
    return null; 
  }
  return (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min).toFixed(point);
};

console.log(
  getRandomNumber(1, 9), 
  getRandomFractionalNumber(1, 9, 4), 
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторение вообще-то от двух лишних функций где можно обойтись одной... но если хочется функцию валидации оформить отдельно, то:

```js
const validateRndArgs = (min, max, digits) => !(min < 0 || max < 0 || max < min || digits < 0) || null; 

const getRandomNumber = (min, max, digits = 0) => (
  validateRndArgs(min, max, digits) && +(
    min + Math.random() * (max + (10 ** -digits) / 2 - min)
  ).toFixed(digits)
);

console.log(
  getRandomNumber(1, 9), 
  getRandomNumber(1, -9),      // null
  getRandomNumber(1, 9, 4), 
  getRandomNumber(1, -9, 4),   // null
);
```

В первом случае из примера, диапазон случайного числа `1..9,5` и округление до целых (== до `9` включительно).
В третьем случае, диапазон `1..9,00005` и округление до десятитысячных (тот же принцип).

Проверки `min < 0` и `max < 0` выглядят совершенно излишними - если они для того чтобы в будущем еще лишних функций наплодить (для диапазонов включающих отрицательные числа), то напрасно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const condition = (min,max) => {
     return !(min < 0 || max < 0 || max < min); 
}

const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return condition(min,max) ? Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min : false;  
};

const getRandomFractionalNumber = (min, max, point) => {
  return condition(min,max) ? Math.round(Math.random() * Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min).toFixed(point) : false;
  }



console.log(getRandomNumber(1, 9));

console.log(getRandomFractionalNumber(1, 9, 4));
```